# Multithreading in Spring Batch

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-batch

I have a Spring Batch application. This app have a step configured to multithread.

```
<bean id="simpleTaskExecutor"
    class="org.springframework.core.task.SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor">
    <property name="concurrencyLimit" value="10"/>
</bean>

<batch:job id="rabbitReadJob" job-repository="jobRepository">
    <batch:step id="step1">
        <batch:tasklet task-executor="simpleTaskExecutor" throttle-limit="10">
            <batch:chunk    
                    reader="CarItemReader"
                    processor="CarItemProcessor"
                    writer="CarItemWriter"
                    commit-interval="2">
            </batch:chunk>
        </batch:tasklet>
    </batch:step>
</batch:job>
```

Commit interval is 2, then a thread of item reader read 2 itens and send to process. Other thread of item reader read others 2 itens and send to process. Itens of both threads execute the process in same time, but we need to wait the first item finish to execute the second. To be easy, I'll post execution log.

```
INFO  06-01 12:44:53,344 - >>>>>>>>>> start processor id 1
INFO  06-01 12:44:53,355 - >>>>>>>>>> start processor id 3
INFO  06-01 12:44:53,362 - >>>>>>>>>> start processor id 5
INFO  06-01 12:44:53,456 - >>>>>>>>>> finish processor id 5
INFO  06-01 12:44:53,456 - >>>>>>>>>> finish processor id 3
INFO  06-01 12:44:53,456 - >>>>>>>>>> start processor id 6
INFO  06-01 12:44:53,456 - >>>>>>>>>> start processor id 4
INFO  06-01 12:44:53,467 - >>>>>>>>>> finish processor id 1
INFO  06-01 12:44:53,467 - >>>>>>>>>> start processor id 2
INFO  06-01 12:44:53,520 - >>>>>>>>>> finish processor id 6
INFO  06-01 12:44:53,520 - >>>>>>>>>> finish processor id 4
INFO  06-01 12:44:53,520 - >>>>>>>>>> writer id 3
INFO  06-01 12:44:53,520 - >>>>>>>>>> writer id 5
INFO  06-01 12:44:53,520 - >>>>>>>>>> writer id 4
INFO  06-01 12:44:53,520 - >>>>>>>>>> writer id 6
INFO  06-01 12:44:53,560 - >>>>>>>>>> finish processor id 2
INFO  06-01 12:44:53,560 - >>>>>>>>>> writer id 1
INFO  06-01 12:44:53,560 - >>>>>>>>>> writer id 2
```

To understanding, first thread process id 1 and id 2. The problem is that id 2 start process only after id 1 finished. Look that the same occurs at second thread (ids 3 and 4) and at third thread (ids 5 and 6).

I want to multithread the chunk. Is that possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A multithreaded step executes each chunk in it's own thread.  So in your case, if you have a `commit-interval` of 2 and the items are read in order, ids 1 and 2 would be processed in sequence on one thread, ids 3 and 4 would be on a second thread, and so on.

The only option for multithreading within a chunk is to use the `AsyncItemProcessor` and `AsyncItemWriter`.  The `AsyncItemProcessor` wraps a regular `ItemProcessor` and executes it in a new thread returning a `Future`.  The `Future` is then passed to the `AsyncItemWriter` which waits for the `Future` to return and then delegates the result to the `ItemWriter` it wraps.  This approach allows you to multithread the processing piece of a chunk.

The only alternative to get each item to be processed within it's own thread would be to change the `commit-interval` to 1.

You can read more about the `AsyncItemProcessor` and `AsyncItemWriter` in the documentation here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/springBatchIntegration.html#asynchronous-processors

Comment: Awesome, I do not know why I missed this part from spring document even visited  it several time.